# How to roll for magical weapons in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

Say I DM a Storm King's Thunder session for Adventurers League. In this hardcover, there are multiple instances of having to randomly distribute magic items. The instructions are as follow:

> Sometimes a treasure hoard contains one or more magic items determined by rolling on the magic item treasure tables in chapter 7 of the Dungeon Master's Guide. When determining a random magic item, roll a d100 (or have a player roll for you) and consult the specified table in the Dungeon Master's Guide. If your players have a "wish list" of magic items, or you think a particular item might be useful to the party, you can forgo the roll and select an item from the table.

Now what would happen if I were to roll a 10 on Table F, which says Weapon +1? It can be any type of weapon, but there are no tables for randomly choosing the type. Is it okay to choose a type that would be useful to one of the player at the table? Maybe ask everyone for their prefered type and roll between those?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Storm King's Thunder Adventurer's League FAQ](http://dndadventurersleague.org/storm-kings-thunder-dm-quest-faq/):

> #### Hey, I’m DMing Storm King's Thunder. Do I roll for treasure?
>
> The overwhelming majority of the magic items contained in Storm King’s Thunder are determined randomly
>   using the various magic item tables found in the Dungeon Master’s Guide. While in previous seasons, the admins
>   took the liberty of determining this treasure in advance, we’ve decided to stick to the spirit of the adventure and
>   allow for random treasure determination—with the following guidance.
>
> - Even though the adventure suggests simply choosing an item off of a table, for official D&D Adventurers
>     League, DMs roll randomly and openly to determine this treasure. However, feel free to take the party
>     composition into account when determining armor or weapon types.

So you must roll randomly, but you can indeed pick a type of weapon that suits your party.

Answer (score -4):

The instructions give you *permission* to decide: not that you need it - you're the DM, the game gives you permission to decide almost anything.

The correct way is *whatever way you choose.*

Comment: I was under the impression that AL was pretty stringy about magic items and staying as close as possible to RAW?

Comment: This answer is wrong in the context of Adventures League play. The AL rules take away some, but not all, DM choices. Magic item selection is one of the things it limits.